# How do I focus on a kendo maskedtextbox

Tags: angular, typescript, kendo-ui, focus

How do I focus on the `kendo-maskedtextbox` after the view initializes in typescript?

Telerik's example [here](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/inputs/api/MaskedTextBoxComponent/#toc-focus) is not very comprehensive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do it like this:

```
import { Component, AfterViewInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';

import { MaskedTextBoxComponent } from '@progress/kendo-angular-inputs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-testing',
  templateUrl: '<kendo-maskedtextbox #TestChild [value]="test"></kendo-maskedtextbox>'
})
export class TestingComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  test: string = "";
  @ViewChild("TestChild", { static: false }) public TestChild: MaskedTextBoxComponent;

  constructor( ) {

  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.TestChild.focus()
  }

}
```